# ByteBuddy Performance in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, byte-buddy

I'm currently thinking about replacing javassist with bytebuddy (mostly for performance reasons).
As a first step I tried using the bytebuddy proxy factory in hibernate (5.2.10).
Unfortunately proxy class generation is now three times slower than before.

Is this expected? A benchmark (https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/testing-the-performance-of-4-java-runtime-code-generators-cglib-javassist-jdk-proxy-byte-buddy/) I found seems to suggest that bytebuddy is supposed to be faster than javassist.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever since this article, Byte Buddy has become quite a bit more advanced and added more features. An unfortunate side effect of adding such features is of course that it takes time to process them.

The feature that is responsible for the decline in performance compared to this early version is the processing of generic type information. Byte Buddy looks into generic types and just checking if they exist costs some extra time, even if a class is non-generic. Also, to take account of generic method overrides that use so-called bridge methods, Byte Buddy interprets the type hierarchy. cglib which ignores generic methods on the other hand can do a more simple analysis but sometimes gets it wrong when dealing with visibility bridges.

Finally, Byte Buddy like cglib faces a trade-off between time to create a class and creating the most efficient code. This trade-off leans strongly towards creating efficient code where Byte Buddy approaches the baseline, i.e. it does not add any overhead by itself but only that of the code being added which is not true for cglib.